# Atom editor: Is there a plugin that can minimize all functions/methods in a file?

Tags: ide, atom-editor

In the Atom editor, I want to be able to minimize all functions in a file at once. For example instead of seeing:

```
v def function1(foo):
    ...
    return foo

v def function2(bar):
    ...
    return bar
```

I'd like to see after a single toggle:

```
> def function1(foo): -

> def function2(bar): -
```

Is there a plug in that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible without any plugins; there are existing keybindings to achieve folding all code, as well as folding at a specific indent level.

On a Mac, the default keybinding to fold all is `alt-cmd-{`, and to unfold is `alt-cmd-}`.

To fold at a specific indent level, the default keybinding (again, on a Mac) is `cmd-k cmd-#`, where `#` is the desired indent level.

To customize your keybindings for folding/unfolding, or to check what the defaults are for your system, searching for "fold" in Settings > Keybindings should bring up the existing options.

Comment: If you came this far, and still use and love atom (and resent Microsoft for what they've done) then `cmd-k cmd-b` is for you.